# Converting from Pressure Assisted to Gravity

Tags: toilet

I have an American Standard 4086 toilet with a Sloan Flushmate pressure assisted unit in it. Is this toilet compatible with a regular gravity flush/fill valve set up if I wanted to remove the flushmate unit?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... interesting proposal and probably a question best answered by the American Standard designs engineers, although good luck getting anything out of them.

You could test the physics of your idea by removing the pressure flush mechanism and rigging a stopper in the tank/cistern that you could manually pull up/off. Fill the tank and pull the stopper, this would tell you if the tank size and bowl/trap design will actually flush by gravity. Then it would be a matter of whether or not a traditional flush valve and fill valve will fit in the holes provided.